# How to send every single message through Winston?

Tags: node.js, winston

I am new to node.js, with almost no background in JavaScript (I'm not a developer, but I currently need to create a small chatbot for testing purpose).

I created a Chatbot thanks to Microsoft Bot framework in node.js and with LUIS. It works great but I would like to implement a nice logging function and discovered Winston.

It works fine to log the messages sent and received to the bot user, because it is custom functions where I specifically ask them to log through Winston. Unfortunately, I don't know (and I've looked on Google, Stackoverflow, winston doc, Botbuilder doc...) how I can ask the modules (BotBuilder, Recognizer,...) to use my custom logger.

Here is an example of what I get:

```
[2018-11-12 10:17:47]-(info) Server's online
WARN: ChatConnector: receive - emulator running without security enabled.
ChatConnector: message received.
[2018-11-12 10:22:49]-(info) [User-IN ] : Hi, how are you doing?
UniversalBot("*") routing "Hi, how are you doing?" from "emulator"
Library("*")recognize() recognized: None(0.1)
```

What should I do to implement Winston in my modules so that every output is correctly formatted?

Thanks a lot!

PS : Here is my (really standard) Winston code

```
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
var winston = require('winston');
const {transports, createLogger, format} = require('winston');

// define the custom settings for each transport (file, console)
var options = {
    file: {
      level: 'silly',
      filename: `logs/Novachat_log.log`,
      handleExceptions: true,
      json: true,
      maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
      maxFiles: 5,
      colorize: false,
    },
    console: {
      level: 'silly',
      handleExceptions: true,
      json: false,
      colorize: true,
    },
  };

  // instantiate a new Winston Logger with the settings defined above
  var logger = winston.createLogger({
    format: format.combine(
      format.timestamp({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
      }),
      format.printf(info => `[${info.timestamp}]-(${info.level}) ${info.message}`)
    ),
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.File(options.file),
      new winston.transports.Console(options.console)
    ],
    exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
  });

  module.exports = logger;
```

And here is how I manually route my IN-OUT messages through Winston:

```
const logIncomingMessage = (event) => {
    logger.info('['+event.address.user.name+'-IN ] : ' + event.text);

};
const logOutgoingMessage = (event) => {
    logger.info('['+event.address.user.name+'-OUT] : ' + event.text);
};

// Middleware for logging
bot.use({
    receive: function (event, next) {
        logIncomingMessage(event);
        next();
    },
    send: function (event, next) {
        logOutgoingMessage(event);
        next();
    }
});
```